# Gulpfile not moving files from source to destination

Tags: visual-studio-2015, angular, gulp, task-runner-explorer

I have created a `gulpfile.js` in **Visual Studio 2015** project. It has been set  to afterbuild. When I compile my project, I see the following message in my *Task Runner Explorer*. Below is the source code of the gulp file

The error message in task runner

```
cmd.exe /c gulp -b "C:\Tom\Personal\PracticeProjects\Angular2\AspNet5Angular2Demo\src\AspNet5Angular2Demo" --color --gulpfile "C:\Tom\Personal\PracticeProjects\Angular2\AspNet5Angular2Demo\src\AspNet5Angular2Demo\Gulpfile.js" default
[12:06:26] 
Process terminated with code 1
```

Gulp file

```
   var gulp = require('gulp');    
gulp.task('moveToLibs', function (done) {
     gulp.src([
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.*.js*',
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.*',
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.*js',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap*.js',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/'));

     gulp.src([
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/css'));
});
```

I have modified the above code as follows but still get the same error. I have installed `merge2` and also mentioned in under `devDependencies` of my `package.json` file.

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "name": "Angular2AspNetCoreDemo",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.17",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "es6-promise": "^3.1.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6",
    "jquery": "^2.2.3"

  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "merge2": "1.0.2"
  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js**

```
  /// <binding AfterBuild='default' />
    var gulp = require('gulp');
    var merge2 = require('merge2');        

    gulp.task('moveToLibs', function (done) {
        return merge2
        (
        gulp.src([
          'node_modules/angular2/bundles/js',
          'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.*.js*',
          'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
          'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.*.js*',
          'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.*.js*',
          'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js*',
          'node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
          'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.*',
          'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.*js',
          'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap*.js',
          'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
        ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/')),

         gulp.src([
          'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
        ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/css')))

    });
```

I have also tried making it as two seperate tasks in my gulp file and still get the same error

```
/// <binding AfterBuild='default' />
var gulp = require('gulp');


gulp.task('moveToLibs', function (done) {
    gulp.src([
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.*.js*',
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.*',
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.*js',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap*.js',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/'))
});
gulp.task('moveToLibsCss', function (done) {

     gulp.src([
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/css'))

});
```

Comment: and you cant use 2 src like that, use merge-stream or merge2 or make it 2 tasks or use run-sequence if you need serial, or use gulp4's serials or parallel. also use return keyword to those gulp.src or async will not get notified

Comment: Also tried as two seperate tasks but still the same error

Comment: use `return gulp.src` not just `gulp.src`, that's huge difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the incorrect glob patterns might be part of the issue, you have:

```
gulp.task('moveToLibs', function (done) {
    gulp.src([
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.*.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.*.js*',
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js*',
      'node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.*',
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.*js',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap*.js',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/'))
});
```

Instead try this:

```
gulp.task('moveToLibs', function (done) {
    gulp.src([
      // 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/js', // folder doesn't exist
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.*.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.*.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.*.js',
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.*',
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
    ]).pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/'))
});
```

Note the differences, they are minor but they are more than likely the cause of the issue. Take a look at [my post](https://ievangelistblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/building-an-angular2-spa-with-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-2-and-typescript-1-7-5/) on using **Angular2** with **ASP.NET Core**, I detail an example gulp file that pulls from `node_modules`.

**Update**

Add a `devDependency` on `gulp-debug` and add:

```
var debug = require("gulp-debug");
```

Then add this to your stream to debug the files to ensure you're getting what you'd expect:

```
gulp.task('moveToLibs', function (done) {
    gulp.src([
      // 'node_modules/angular2/bundles/js', // folder doesn't exist
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.*.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.*.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.*.js',
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.min.js',
      'node_modules/angular2/es6/dev/src/testing/shims_for_IE.js',
      'node_modules/systemjs/dist/*.*',
      'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
      'node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js'
    ])
    .pipe(debug())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./wwwroot/libs/'))
});
```

Comment: I am unfortunately getting the same error. Very frustrating

Comment: God news. it worked. Thanks David, I had looked at your blog. I just added this to the last line gulp.task('default', ['moveToLibs', 'moveToLibsCss']);

Comment: Awesome, thanks -- I appreciate the upvote and accept

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the name of your task to `default` like

```
gulp.task('moveToLibs', function (done) {...}
```

or add an empty default task and make it depend on your `moveToLibs` like:

```
gulp.task('default',['moveToLibs']);
```

Comment: Tried that getting the same error as mentioned in the post above

Comment: @Tom, all right, is your gulp file named `Gulpfile.js` with capital letter ?

Comment: @Tom that could be the problem . Because the error message on your question has a `Gulpfile.js` with capital letter

Comment: changed the file to upper case but that still didnt work

Comment: @Tom is it still the same error? Is the path in the error message correct?  Because I don't think gulp is able to read the file at all